# ArgumentError invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 , FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

Tags: chef-infra

While executing below code in node machine using command chef-client i am facing "ArgumentError  invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" this error.

Here is my sample code:

```
my_secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/tmp/secret")
my_secret_databag = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load(“userdata”,”xyz”, my_secret_key)

user 'devops' do
  comment 'devops user' 
  uid 101
  home '/home/devops'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  password my_secret_databag['password']
end
```

Comment: Which line is raising the exception?

Comment: at below lines                                                                         
 my_secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/tmp/secret")
my_secret_databag = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load(“userdata”,”xyz”, my_secret_key)

Comment: That's still two lines. Which one

Comment: my_secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/tmp/secret")

Comment: How did you generate your key? We usually use base64-endcoded random data but it sounds like you just use binary randomness?

Comment: i used "“openssl rand –base64 512 | tr –d ‘\r\n’ >  secret”,  generated this key in powershell then copied to node machine(ec2 instance) using winscp to /tmp dir.